# Extract the architecture from a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, architecture, continuous-integration

Documenting architecture is very nice and helpful, except for it takes a lot of time to do and gets outdated very fast.

I know that there are amazing tools out there that sort of extract the architecture (i.e. dependencies between classes and so on) from a given project. For example, I have used [Doxygen](http://doxygen.nl/) in my C++ projects before. It is true that Doxygen is a general purpose documentation tool, but is also provides some nice class hierarchy than can be useful as an *overview* of the architecture. The clear advantage of this approach is that it is well suited for continuous integration.

Right now I am working in a Typescript (~Javascript) project that uses the React framework (also Redux, if that matters). I was wondering if there is a similar tool for Typescript/React projects, that allows me to automatically extract the class hierarchy of the project and this way provide some minimal architecture documentation.

Thank you for any advice!

PS: I am not completely sure if this question is allowed in StackOverflow. If that is the case, I would appreciate very much if someone tells me where should I be posting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend 2 tools i found very usefull for me: 
    Typedoc 
-> https://typedoc.org/ 
    apiDoc  
-> (website) http://apidocjs.com 
            -> (very cool and easy guide) https://speakerdeck.com/rottmann/api-documentation?slide=12

Typedoc will help you with an automatic extraction with the class hierarchy of your projects, the other will help you with api documentation auto generated.

hope you'll find what you need here.